# erro na execução de aplicação c# asp.net entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp

Bom dia,

O meu projeto começou do nada apresentar esse erro.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Já tentei reinstalar o system.net.http mas nada

Como solucionar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente instalar o System.Net.Http v 4.0.0 pelo pacote nuget no projeto.

Comment: Deu certo, reinstalei ele e atualizei o web.config, valeu